# client-side node module doesn't work after browserify

Tags: node.js, autocomplete, client-side, browserify, node-modules

I'm trying to develop an app under node.js. I need a module named autocomplete so I did

```
npm install -S autocomplete
```

and that worked fine. `packages.json` was updated and everything.

But I need the functionality of autocomplete on the client side. The most popular solution to this problem seems to be to use browserify, so I installed that globally and it seems to work.

Now according to everything I've read, I should be able to:

```
cd node_modules
browserify autocomplete/index.js > bundle.js
mv bundle.js ../public/lib/js/
```

and then in views/index.html I should be able to have

```
<script src="lib/js/bundle.js">
```

and finally I should be able to say

```
var auto = new Autocomplete();
```

because the Autocomplete object is defined in the autocomplete module and that's how the instructions say to instantiate it.

But unfortunately my browser says `Autocomplete is not defined` so it's clearly not getting the message.

What is wrong with the above?

Answer (score 1):

When you run Browserify, create it as a `standalone` module:

```
browserify autocomplete/index.js --standalone Autocomplete > autocomplete.js
```

I'm only changing the name here for simplicity - call it whatever you want.

Then, when you run this in the browser as you have it currently, `new Autocomplete()` should be available.

**Edit**
While this is doable, the docs for this module are missing, and the module you are reading the docs for seems missing.

There isn't a need to go to this trouble when you can use something like [`typeahead`](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) which is already built for the browser.

Comment: Thank you this worked! I'm kind of stunned that in the hours I've spent reading about browserify, I never read about the "--standalone" flag. I guess usually it's not needed? Can you tell me what is different about "autocomplete" that it was necessary?

Comment: Any time a module uses only `module.exports` then the browser doesn't have any clue what the module is called. That's what `--standalone` does for you. I'm building a library right now with the same thing. Feel free to upvote :)

Comment: Hi unfortunately even though I was able to instantiate the object using your solution, calling methods on the object gave another error. I instantiated `auto = new Autocomplete()`, but then `auto.initialize(data)` yielded `Uncaught TypeError: getInitialElements is not a function`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, or how you are doing it, but if you want to use that library on the client side, this is the way to do it. What ever the other errors are, I would need more info to help.

Comment: The usage is pulled from the sample code on the module's page at https://www.npmjs.com/package/triecomplete. I just plugged in the code they suggested as a demonstration of how to use the module. The method that fails is an internal method in the autocomplete module, so it seems like browserify is not sending everything to the client side that is needed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `initialize` looks like it requires a function, not data.

Comment: My code is taken directly from the module's page, which says `var auto = new Autocomplete();
      var data = ['fruit', 'app', 'apple', 'banana'];
      auto.initialize(data);` My code then fails with the above error at the `auto.initialize()` step.

Comment: Also, the last commit to that library was three years ago.

Comment: Yes, do you think maybe the module just isn't written very well?

Comment: The link you gave me is for `triecomplete` which isn't what you installed. And that repo seems to be missing.  If all you need is auto complete functionality, use typeahead from Twitter.

Comment: And the errors you're seeing aren't from an incorrect answer, just incorrect usage.

Comment: I apologize if I have caused any frustration. However, the link I gave was correct. The module is called 'triecomplete' but the instructions as given there are `npm install -S autocomplete`. I don't know why. I am sure my usage is incorrect, but that's why I'm asking the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look at the module name in npm. You are installing `https://www.npmjs.com/package/autocomplete`

Comment: The source for autocomplete` shows `initialize` with a function as a parameter. I've answered the question you originally asked, and the library your reading documentation for is not the library being installed. If it were, then it would be expecting an array not a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83649/discussion-between-nttaylor-and-kelly-j-andrews).

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out because Autocomplete is not exported to the global scope.
Try this in the file where you use Autocomplete, for example in the app.js:

```
var Autocomplete = require('autocomplete');
var auto = new Autocomplete();
```

Then

```
browserify app.js > bundle.js
mv bundle.js ../public/lib/js/
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately this doesn't work for me because "require" is not defined on the client side. This is another question that I know a lot has been written about, but so far I haven't found a solution! How do you get "require" defined for client-side usage?

Comment: browserify will recursively analyze all the require() calls in your app in order to build a bundle you can serve up to the browser in a single <script> tag.

Comment: How would your solution above work when the code has to be located on the client side and the client side doesn't know what "require" is?

Comment: are you referring to the part that says "A module name or file to bundle.require(). Optionally use a colon separator to set the target."? That sentence is not clear. Do you know how it is meant to be used?